# Java: Need some advice on code reuse

Tags: java, refactoring, reusability

I have this big class I created, as part of a project I got for homework.
The class contains data members as well as some methods, and now I need to create another (almost) **identical** class.
it is almost identical, because the only difference is a constant number that appears here and there in the code.

for example, if the original class has:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
        labels[i][j]=new Label(panel, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
        labels[i][j].setImage(empty);
    }
}
```

the new class should have:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        labels[i][j]=new Label(panel, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
        labels[i][j].setImage(empty);
    }
}
```

and if the original class has:

```
labels=new Label[8][8];
```

the new class should have:

```
labels=new Label[10][10];
```

meaning the only difference is 10 instead of 8, several times in the code.

In what way can I reuse the code here?
Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: why not have this class take the value as a parameter and then use that as a variable?

Comment: Maybe try to put it in a field initialized in class constructor? Something like:
`public Clazz(final Integer size){
    this.size = size;
}`

Comment: You should make your new class Extend the existing one, and override the methods. On a second note, magic numbers suck... define constants that you can change in other implementations.

Comment: create a method that takes an int arg, and use that in place of the 8 or 10

Comment: Make the number into a member variable reference. Set the variable from a constructor parameter. There you go -- now you only need one class, you can reuse the whole thing.

Comment: OK! I didn't know java allows variables in instantiations!  
as far as I recall, C\C++ doesn't allow this, for example: 
int[][] array=new int[var][var].
I'll just use a variable, like @devshorts suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use class attributes:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final int labelsSize;
    private final Label[][] labels;
    public MyClass(final int labelsSize) { 
        this.labelsSize = labelsSize;
        this.labels = new Label[labelsSize][labelsSize];
    }
    // ...
    for (int i=0; i<labelsSize; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<labelsSize; j++) {
            labels[i][j]=new Label(panel, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
            labels[i][j].setImage(empty);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! didn't realize Java allows this. 
One question though: why did you mark labels as final? because I cannot afford that in my code... :(

Comment: It is a good practice to mark final if you have the intention on assigning them once at the construction of the class, and never re-assign them later. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in that number (either 8 or 10) as a parameter for this method, or as an argument for the constructor. Then set it as an instance variable and access it in this code.